# How can I stop my iMac's remote management connection from defaulting to Wi-Fi?

Tags: macos, networking, vnc, routing, apple-remote-desktop

I have a 2011 Mac mini connected to my 2008 iMac via Ethernet cable. The Mac mini is configured to accept remote management sessions, but the problem is when the Mac mini's AirPort is turned on, the remote management software defaults to the Wi-Fi connection versus the Ethernet connection, resulting in a much slower refresh rate. Is there any way to force the remote management software to use the Ethernet connection versus the Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: You need to explain more about your networks. What network is the iMac's Ethernet connected to? What network is the iMac's Wi-Fi connected to, when it's on? What IP subnets (IP address ranges) do these two networks use? How are these two networks connected to each other? How does the Mac mini connect to these two networks? How do you have the network interfaces ranked in the Network panel of System Preferences on the iMac? On the Mac mini?

Comment: The iMac's ethernet connection is connected to the mac mini. The iMac and the mac mini have the same wifi configuration. I checked the mac mini and the ethernet connection is on top.

Comment: The ethernet is also at the top on the iMac though the stop light is orange not green.

Answer (score 0):

The default is as per Interface "Service Order" for any connection on your iMac

*UNLESS* - the connection in the software was made prior to the Ethernet cable being connected, in which case it will stay WiFi, until you restart software, or disconnect WiFi, and the app has to connect again.

Head to the Network, under System Preferences, and set your 'Service Order' accordingly.

Comment: I checked the iMac's network configuration and the Ethernet was at the top but since they are connected directly via Ethernet configuration that I probably don't have the configuration right because the stop light at the left of the connection is orange and it reads that I have a self assigned IP.

Comment: Is there some way to share the iMac's wifi internet connection when the mac mini is connected to the iMac via Ethernet cable?

Comment: I did attempt to enable Internet Sharing on my iMac through the Ethernet port but then I am unable to Remote Desktop into the mac mini.